# ProductFlavours with only change in resources

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-productflavors

I have an application which is completely developed.
Now I have to create same application with minimal changes only in `mipmap`
folders and `strings.xml`

I have created Product Flavours in build.gradle as

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'sonar'
    apply plugin: 'sonar-runner'

    android {
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "16.1.1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        }
        productFlavors {
            flavour1 {
                buildConfigField "String", "BASE_SERVER_URL", '"http://flavour1.com"'
                buildConfigField "String", "CITY_ID", "1"
            }
            flavour2 {
                buildConfigField "String", "BASE_SERVER_URL", '"http://flavour2.com"'
                buildConfigField "String", "CITY_ID", "2"
            }
        }
    }

    repositories {

    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
        compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
        compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
        compile 'com.eftimoff:androidplayer:1.0.3@aar'
        compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
        compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
        compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
        compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.5.2'
        compile('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7') {
            exclude module: 'stax'
            exclude module: 'stax-api'
            exclude module: 'xpp3'
        }
    compile files('libs/xmlutils.jar')
    compile 'cc.cloudist.acplibrary:library:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile files('libs/json-20140107.jar')
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:4.0.0-rc.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.4@aar'
    compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-1.0.4-debug.jar')
}
```

and modified my folder structure as

```
Project
--/app
  --/src
    --/flavour1
      --/res
        --strings.xml
    --/flavour2
      --/res
        --strings.xml
    --/main
      --/java
      --/res
      --/AndroidManifest.xml
```

and then I'm getting 2 errors

```
`1`

`error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String
    public static final String PAID_DETAILS = "p";
                  ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.`

`2`

Execution failed for task ':app:compileflavour1DebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

EDIT:

Changed folder structure as below to work as expected

```
Project
--/app
  --/src
    --/flavour1
      --/res
        --/values
          --strings.xml
    --/flavour2
      --/res
        --/values               
          --strings.xml
    --/main
      --/java
      --/res
      --/AndroidManifest.xml
```

Comment: "public static final String PAID_DETAILS = "p";" - where is this present ?

Comment: in one of my classes, it worked fine when there were no Productflavours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
buildConfigField "String", "CITY_ID", "1"
```

It will create in your `BuildConfig`:

```
public static final String CITY_ID = 1;
```

and it is an error.

**You have to use**

```
buildConfigField "String", "CITY_ID", "\"1\""
```

At the same way you have to change `buildConfigField "String", "CITY_ID", "2"`

Comment: It was a great pleasure to get an answer from your Sir Gabriele Mariotti. You solved my problem, but my strings are not getting picked from respective flavour. Is there anything wrong in the way I created them ?

Comment: sry my bad!!!!! got that fixed too... was using strings.xml in res folder. changed it to res-values-strings and it worked fine.